# OrderBy() method of Firebase.Xamarin doesn't sort the data

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

This is a question about Firebase.Xamarin NuGet package. I'm using the statement `await Client.Child(FirebaseKeys.Users).OrderBy("FirstName").OnceAsync<object>();` to sort the users by first name, but I don't get the users in sorted order. In the source code there is a comment stating that "this is used mainly for following filtering queries and due to firebase implementation the data may actually not be ordered." I'm not sure whether it's even possible to sort the data at all.

Comment: If you can't get Firebase to order your results, you can always materialize the query to a `List<User>` or appropriate structure, then order them in memory.

Comment: Likely you're undoing the order when you get the data from the `object`. You'll need to loop over the [DataSnapshot.Children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#children) or [listen for Child events[(https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#child-events) to maintain the order.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Firebase.Xamarin Github Code, it clearly states in the method documentation as such:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Order data by given <see cref="propertyName"/>. Note that this is used mainly for following filtering queries and due to firebase implementation
        /// the data may actually not be ordered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="child"> The child. </param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"> The property name. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="OrderQuery"/>. </returns>
        public static OrderQuery OrderBy(this ChildQuery child, string propertyName)
        {
            return child.OrderBy(() => propertyName);
        }
```

In effect, the data **may not** be sorted as required.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Mobile view of SO is a little difficult. I didn't read it properly. I will leave my answer without editing or deleting so other people can read as I posted the actual source code with the documentation. Thanks for pointing out!